# Trying to set a nullable relationship in Entity Framework results in compile time error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

So I need a `Task` model where I need to set the `User` relationship to allow for null values:

```
public class Task
{
    public Task()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }     
    public virtual User PersonResponsible { get; set; }
}
```

If I try to set the `User` to be nullable like this:

```
public class Task
{
    public Task()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }     
    public virtual User? PersonResponsible { get; set; }
}
```

I get a compile time error:

> The type 'Models.User' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'

I've tried googling this but I don't really understand any of the fixes, nor are most of the questions related to Entity Framework. Ideas?

Comment: Only value types can be specified as null though a '?'. A reference type is inherently nullable. Try simply removing the '?'.

Comment: If User is a class it's already a reference type and therefore can be null. There is no reason to wrap it in Nullable<>

Comment: This is odd, I've tried setting the foreign key property to null in the past without success.

Comment: Also, is there any reason for the downvote?

Comment: @EchoLogic You can only use `?` for value types (`int`, `double`, `DateTime` etc, etc). A `User` can always be null (unless you defined it at a struct).

Comment: Is there any mapping involved here? `UserId` (the foreign key) must be nullable in the database to begin with, and/or be mapped as optional.